# Why datas not update after navigate on react native?

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-navigation, updates, tabnavigator

I have a basic tab navigation HOME-UPLOAD-PROFILE. 'HOME' screen has values which fetch with an api from a different web site. After user log in navigation system direct user to this home page and "fetch" working well. But when i upload something using 'UPLOAD' screen  and then return 'HOME' screen datas not updating. Whereas 'componentDidMount' should works everytime and bring datas every clicking 'HOME' screen I could not find any solution or answere

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    //Burada kullanıcı yoksa ülkeleri getireceğiz
    const rest = await fetch(
      'https://www.birdpx.com/mobile/fotografgetir/' + this.state.page,
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(datam)
      }
    );

    const gelenVeri = await rest.text();
    let convertedVeri = JSON.parse(gelenVeri);

    this.setState({
      data: convertedVeri
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check by logging if `componentDidMount` is triggered.

`componentDidMount` won't be triggered when you navigate between tabs in tabNavigator, except for the first time when tabNavigator is mounted.

You can choose one of the following 2 ways to implement what you need.

**1. Use global redux state instead of component state. (Recommended)**

You can implement `redux` to your project (if you aren't using). Use redux state in `Home` component instead of current component state.

On `Upload` screen, once uploading is done you can change the redux store by dispatching an action. This will instantly reflect on your `Home` component.

**2. Fetch data on component focus event**

If you want to catch the focus event for a specific tab component, you can use `didFocus` event listener of navigation lifecycle.

```js
const didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didFocus',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didFocus', payload);
  }
);

// Remove the listener when you are done
didFocusSubscription.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-navigation, components do not unmount when you navigate from one screen to the next on a stack navigator.
You can listen to navigation lifecycle events in a component (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-prop/#addlistener---subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)

or if you are using `withNavigationFocus` HOC for passing navigation prop to a component you can use the `isFocused` prop to know about the recent focus on you component.